# Why equals might not return true

Tags: java, equals

I have this string: `"no_questions_by_user"` in a variable named result.

than I do this check:

```
if ( result != null && result.equals( "no_user_id" ) )
{
        Log.d( "Post execute: " , "NOOOT  OKKKK - no user id" );    
}
else
if ( result != null && result.equals( "database_error" ) )
{
        Log.d( "Post execute: " , "NOOOT  OKKKK - database error" );    
}
else
if ( result != null && result.equals( "no_questions_by_user" ) )
{           
        Log.d( "Post execute: " , "NOOOT  OKKKK - no questions by user so far" );   
}
else
{
  Log.d( "MyQuestionsActivity" , "In JSON parsing area.." );                
}
```

and it always goes to the last else. But in my understanding it should really go to the block which checks `result.equals( "no_questions_by_user" )`

any idea why that block does not get executed?

Thanks!!

Comment: print out the string named result ...

Comment: `equals(...)` will return false if the two Strings are not the same. Period. You've got a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: I have debugging statements there and it shows that result value is "no_questions_by_user" which is what confuses me.

Comment: Still the bug is yours. The Strings are not the same -- that's the only explanation. Try trimming the String, analyzing the bytes in the String. Again the bug is yours, not Java's.

Comment: @GeekedOut it can't be if result is declared as a String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks good. Your variable `result` must have another value.

My guess is that there are some whitespaces at the end or beginning of your result string.

Comment: that is right. You answered first so I'll accept the answer in 10 min when the system lets me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I think this code is a hot mess.

I'd write one method that took in a result and looked up a message in a Map.  All those if tests are making my eyes bleed:

```
private static final Map<String, String> LOG_MESSAGE_MAP;

static {
    LOG_MESSAGE_MAP = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // put all your result, message pairs in here
}

public void logResultDependentMessage(String result) {
    log.debug(LOG_MESSAGE_MAP.get(result));
}
```

Now adding new result, message pairs just means inserting into the map.  If you're using something like Spring you can do it in configuration and not touch the code.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
result.trim().equals( "no_questions_by_user" )
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you see "no_questions_by_user" in a debbugger ?

You can try to trim it before the test, as spaces are hard to detect in debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no white spaces in the value of the "result" variable. 
Before entering the if statements, you can do a print line like this one.

```
System.out.println("The Value of result variable is=\"" + result + "\"");
```

You might as well do this

```
if ( result != null && result.trim().equals( "no_questions_by_user" ) )
{           
        Log.d( "Post execute: " , "NOOOT  OKKKK - no questions by user so far" );   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use some static variables to store your strings, so you avoid typing errors.